# How could I change the baud rate of my STM32 UART by receiving input from another microcontroller?

Tags: stm32, esp32

I'm currently trying to change the baudrate at runtime for my STM32 based on whatever input my ESP32 sends it over UART. I'm. not really sure how to go about it or if its even possible to do so.

Basically I'm sending a uint32 over UART to the STM32 and hoping it is receiving it as the number I'm sending then aborting and deinitializing the UART, reinitializing it with the new baud rate and then initializing the UART again.

However, this does not seem to be having any effect. I can't tell if what I'm sending it just not making it to the STM32 as the value I intended or if it's receiving the value and just not doing anything. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
uint8_t Rx_data[100] = "<Hello World\n>";
int baud = 115200;
uint8_t Tx_data[100];
int main(void)
{
/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */



/* USER CODE END 1 */

/* MCU Configuration------------------------------------------- 
-------------*/

/* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface 
and the Systick. */
HAL_Init();

/* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

/* USER CODE END Init */

/* Configure the system clock */
SystemClock_Config();

/* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

/* USER CODE END SysInit */

/* Initialize all configured peripherals */
MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_USART1_UART_Init();
MX_USART2_UART_Init();
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

// Transmit data via UART

/* USER CODE END 2 */

/* Infinite loop */
/* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
while (1)
{
//    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5); // Blink
//    HAL_Delay(1000); // Delay blink for 1 second



HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, (uint8_t*)Tx_data, 100, 100); // 
Receive comms from ESP32


  uint8_t Tx_value = Tx_data;

  if(baud != Tx_value) {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5); // Blink
      HAL_Delay(1000); // Delay blink for 1 second

      baud = Tx_value;
      Change_baud(baud);

  }

  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,(uint8_t*) Tx_data, 100, 100); // Transmit comms from ESP32 to terminal




  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, Rx_data, sizeof(Rx_data), 100);


/* USER CODE END WHILE */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
 //HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, Rx_data, 4, 1000);





}
 /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

void Change_baud(int baud) {
HAL_UART_DeInit(&huart2);
MX_USART2_UART_Init_baud(baud);
HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t*)Rx_data, 100);

}
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init_baud(int baud)
{

 /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

 /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

 /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

 /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
 huart2.Instance = USART2;
 huart2.Init.BaudRate = baud;
 huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
 huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
 huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
 huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
 huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
 huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
 if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
 {
   Error_Handler();
 }
 /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

 /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

 }
```

I realize this is not the best written code, I'm VERY new to STM32 and how to program it.

Comment: There are so many problems here I don't really know where to start. Please don't post pictures of your code, just paste in (correctly formatted) code. Calling HAL_UART_Receive() with a byte count of 100 means it will try to receive 100 bytes. You do not check the return value from that function as well. What is 'baud'? You've not provided enough code. You seem to be somehow using two different UARTs. I don't think anyone can help until you clear up all this confusion.

Comment: Also, that is just the (highly confusing) STM32 code. Is there also some ESP32 code we should know about?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to posting questions I'm still very new to this. I'm still trying to figure out how to code the STM32 I'm using as well and I've barely scratched the surface of how the HAL functions work. Baud is supposed to be the value I'm using to update the buad rate of UART2 with the value received from UART1 coming from my ESP32.

Comment: Break it down into steps then. Can you send something from the ESP32 to the STM32? Start with that, and ignore everything else until you know that works. Also, please heed and fix any warnings that your compiler is giving you. They almost always mean your code is incorrect.

Comment: I’m doing this by sending a command from one controller to the other with the desired baud rate, the receiving controller sends a response with the effective baud rate (usually the same) which is configured immediately after the response was (completely) sent out to the wire. The initiating controller receives the response with the new baud rate value and configures its interface accordingly.

Comment: You're trying to do too much here without a clear understanding of what you're doing. Remove all references to UART2 and just get something working with UART1. And please investigate all warnings the compiler is giving you. Understand them and fix them properly. This, for example, is completely bogus: uint8_t Tx_value = Tx_data;

Comment: Hello! I'm just now getting a chance to see these, thank you for the input. Yes, I have been able to send something from the ESP to the STM. @pmacfarlane . Also thank you HS2 , the main problem I'm having is that I can send words and numbers I'm just not sure how to store that value I'm receiving so that I can use it to change the baud.

Comment: The UART2 stuff is actually how I'm validating it's working. I'm receiving the information from UART1's Rx line and then feeding it to UART2 so I can see if what was sent is changing the baud rate :/